# My question was unilaterally deleted because it "copies too much content from elsewhere"

Tags: discussion

I can happily shorten [my question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/106191/10763), but I quoted the Reddit comment in full to preserve context and integrity? What ought be removed?

Also, my question spurred an answer with 5 upvotes. So I don't think length's a snag?

Comment: I can't comment on your question while it is deleted, but I have taken the liberty of editing the question in a way that I believe preserves your intent.  Take a look and feel free to edit further if I phrased things in a way that you do not agree with.

Comment: @BenMiller Thanks. Looks great! No edits necessary.

Answer (score 3):

> This question copies too much content from elsewhere - please rephrase
>   the key bits it in your own words and only (very) selectively quote to
>   the referenced material (you can still link it). You can flag for
>   undeletion once that's done.

What part of the comment needs clarification? Would it not stand to reason that copying a full question as you did, from another site isn’t a good thing?

I’d delete the whole thing and simply ask a question in your own words.

Comment: The question was asked and deleted in less than 1 day. Doesn’t that seem a little fast? And to be fair, the OP was not copying someone else’s question. He was copying someone else’s *answer*, because he had a question about it. I totally agree with everyone that the question should be edited down to a tiny fraction of it’s length, but how can we do that now that it is deleted? It is a waste to make him write a new question - there is already a good answer there, and all it needs is a good edit to the question, which I would be happy to make.

Comment: I learned something new today!  I learned that I can edit deleted questions.  I have done that, and issued a moderator flag for undeletion.  In my opinion, this is a great example of deletion by a moderator that was completely unnecessary.  It simply needed a good edit.  It wasn't even closed; just deleted.  I don't get it....

Comment: @BenMiller I hesitated between deletiona and closure, but chose deletion because a quote of that length is an unambiguous copyright violation (I checked the reddit T&Cs, you are only giving them a licence when you post there), so I didn't think it should be left visible in that form. I'm not actually sure if there's any existing S.E. policy on this, if anyone can find one I'd be happy to change my approach in future cases.

Comment: @BenMiller There's [a help center for referencing material written by others](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). While it's focused on the answer, it also applies to the question, especially on "*Do **not** copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own.*" which was the *issue* with the original revision. (anyway, the question has been undeleted after your edit)

Comment: @BenMiller and yes, OP can still edit their deleted posts (not self-deleted one to prevent abuse) and flag for undeletion, which is the very request of the mods.